# ng-repeat: access key and value for each object in array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects and I am using an `ng-repeat` to iterate over them, which is easy.  The array looks something like this:

```
$scope.steps = [
    {companyName: true},
    {businessType: true},
    {physicalAddress: true}
];
```

And my `ng-repeat` attribute looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="step in steps"> ... </div>
```

In each iteration, `step` is equal to one of the objects, as expected.  Is there anyway to access both the key and the value of the `step` object?  So that I could do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(stepName, isComplete) in steps"> ... </div>
```

Where `stepName` == `'companyName'` and `isComplete` == `true`.  I've tried doing this exact thing but `stepName` always just ends up being the index of the step object (which makes sense).  I'm just trying to figure out if there is another way to write the `ng-repeat` syntax so that I can get the key and the value.

Thanks for any ideas/suggestions.  Much appreciated.

PS.  My current work around is to just do this in my controller:

```
$scope.stepNames = [];
angular.forEach($scope.steps, function(isComplete, stepName){
     $scope.stepNames.push({stepName: stepName, isComplete: isComplete});
});
```

And then to iterate over that, but it would be nice to do it all in the view

Answer (score 109, accepted):

A repeater inside a repeater

```
<div ng-repeat="step in steps">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in step">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without having to create two `<div>`s for every one of my steps?  I could make it work but it kinda seems like a pain to have to adjust my css to work around the extra `<div>`...

Comment: Well you have two iterations, so no (not that I know of, could be wrong). You have to first iterate the array, and then the keys, so an inner loop is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: Ok, sounds good.  I was just hoping there was some cool `ng-repeat` syntax that I didn't know of like `ng-repeat="(key,val) for step in steps"` or something similar to `ng-options`.  Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Yeah, Im checking out the docs now, seeing if anything pops out.

Comment: You could probably solve this by writing a directive and having the link function manipulate the data.

Comment: my problem is my key is an object it self but i don't know why i cannot get {{key.name}} forexample

Answer (score 17):

In fact, your data is not well design. You'd better use something like :

```
$scope.steps = [
    {stepName: "companyName", isComplete: true},
    {stepName: "businessType", isComplete: true},
    {stepName: "physicalAddress", isComplete: true}
];
```

Then it is easy to do what you want :

```
<div ng-repeat="step in steps">
 Step {{step.stepName}} status : {{step.isComplet}}
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rX7ba/

Comment: I think KayakDave's design is better, but again it's hard to tell without knowing exactly what the data is for.

Comment: I dont think that an object with a property value designed as a key is a good idea. The proof is that the object has to be inspected by its key/value pairs which is kind of reflection. Anyway if the solution provided suits better...fine, we dont know exactly what is done with the data.

Answer (score 7):

In case this is an option for you, if you put your data into object form it works the way I think you're hoping for:

```
$scope.steps = {
 companyName: true,
 businessType: true,
 physicalAddress: true
};
```

Here's a fiddle of this:  http://jsfiddle.net/zMjVp/

Comment: Yea I agree, this seems like a better data structure. Although, it's hard to tell without knowing exactly what the data is for.

Comment: This doesn't preserve the order of key-value pairs in case you want it to be preserved.

Comment: And judging from the data structure it would seem order matters.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with the way you designed your data. To me in terms of semantics, it just doesn't make sense. What exactly is steps for?

**Does it store the information of one company?**

If that's the case steps should be an object (see KayakDave's answer) and each "step" should be an object property.

**Does it store the information of multiple companies?**

If that's the case, steps should be an array of objects.

```
$scope.steps=[{companyName: true, businessType: true},{companyName: false}]
```

In either case you can easily iterate through the data with one (two for 2nd case) ng-repeats.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, without the need for nesting the repeaters.

From the [Angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> It is possible to get ngRepeat to iterate over the properties of an
>   object using the following syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in steps"> {{key}} : {{value}} </div>
```

Comment: good only for $scope.steps = {
 companyName: true,
 businessType: true,
 physicalAddress: true
};

Comment: not for original request $scope.steps = [
    {companyName: true},
    {businessType: true},
    {physicalAddress: true}
];

Answer (score -1):

seems like in Angular 1.3.12 you do not need the inner ng-repeat anymore, the outer loop returns the values of the collection is a single map entry