# Angularjs - Dynamic ng-repeat Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a dynamic page, that depending of some aspects shows one list or another list, both arrays have different variable names. I tried to use somethings to put dynamic ng-repeat expression but without success.

Anyone has some suggestion? I made a fiddle to explain what i need.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsToShow" >
    <!--THIS IS THE EXPRESSION THAT I WANT DYNAMIC-->
 {{item.name}}, {{item.title}}
```

[fiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/eTTZj/867/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want to do. What's wrong with the fiddle?

Comment: With "dynamic" you mean what?

Comment: He means dynamic because fields have different names in the two lists. ( `title` versus `titleBig` for instance)

Comment: I understand now. There's no concrete answer for this situation, I would advise you to either organise your data homogenously, or if they are semantically different, create a template for each and use an ng-switch to determine which template to use

Comment: Let me explain in a better way. I have and app with 30 input fields. In each field i want a modal with the list of every possible values for that field. but that information comes from a different array for every field and I am trying to make a generic modal to every input field

Answer (score 0):

You could use operators :

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemsToShow" >
     {{item.name || item.firstname}},  {{item.title || item.titleBig}}
   </div>
```

This will pick the existing property in your list.

If it's unsunstainable for many, many lists you can also do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsToShow"></div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me explain in a better way. I have and app with 30 input fields. In each field i want a modal with the list of every possible values for that field. but that information comes from a different array with different keys (email,name,phone) for every field and I am trying to make a generic modal to every input field

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTTZj/869/). When you want to be 'dynamic', just code the logic inside the controller and set the `$scope.itemsToShow`with different arrays, so your view hasn't to change.

Like this:

```
....
var show_items_2 = true;
/*Whatever you want to do here*/
if(show_items_2) {
   $scope.itemsToShow = items2;
} else {
    $scope.itemsToShow = items;
}
```

When you want to have different `keys` inside your array ('name' and 'nameBig'), you have to access the items differently (through (key, value)). See this [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544904/ng-repeat-access-key-and-value-for-each-object-in-array-of-objects).

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsToShow"></div>
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
    {{key}} : {{value}}
</div>
```