# AngularJS - ng-repeat over array with string index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, associative-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to `ng-repeat` over array with string index? Please see below snippet of the code-

Below code is in a controller.

```
$scope.days = ["mon", "tue", "wed" .... "sun"];
$scope.arr = [];
$scope.arr["mon"] = ["apple","orange"];
$scope.arr["tue"] = ["blue","swish"];
.
.
.
$scope.arr["sun"] = ["pineapple","myfruit","carrot"];
```

Question - How to `ng-repeat` like something below, is it possible?

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">{{day}}
    <span ng-repeat="item in arr(day)">{{item}}</span> 
    <-- Something like "arr(day)", can it be done in angular -->
</div>
```

Comment: you want to do it in controller or template?

Comment: @sumair - In template(the html file)

Comment: Out of interest why aren't you using an object?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - I could use an object too. But curious to know how to do it for an array? BTW, is it possible for an object?

Comment: Please find the similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544904/ng-repeat-access-key-and-value-for-each-object-in-array-of-objects

Answer (score 4):

You can just use normal syntax for item in an array.
Please refer my fiddle

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='default' ng-init='init()'>
  <div ng-repeat='day in days'>
    <strong>{{day}}</strong><br/>
    <span ng-repeat="item in arr[day]">{{item}} </span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DoTH/evcv4tu5/3/

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets to access object/array fields/elements.

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">{{day}}
    <span ng-repeat="item in arr[day]">{{item}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this `ng-repeat="item in arr[day]"`

Answer (score 0):

You can print the item number too.

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
    {{day}}
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in arr[day]">Item #{{key + 1}}: {{value}}
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely possible. See a working example below:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {
  $scope.days = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "sun"];
  $scope.arr = [];
  $scope.arr["mon"] = ["apple", "orange"];
  $scope.arr["tue"] = ["blue", "swish"];
  $scope.arr["sun"] = ["pineapple", "myfruit", "carrot"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="day in days">
      <strong>{{day}}</strong>
      <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="item in arr[day]">{{item}}</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```